# PDF bookmarks according to figure titles or labels

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I have dozens of figures that I am going to include in one PDF file using the following code combination:

```
% allpdfs.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\myimagelist}[2]{\includepdf[fitpaper=true]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\input{filelist}
\end{document}
```

where my filelist contains pdf figures and their locations:

```
% filelist.tex
\myimagelist{some label}{some path/pdffile1}
\myimagelist{some other label}{some path/pdffile2}
% ....
```

my question is, how do I modify first code to include bookmarks in PDF according to the titles or labels of the figures I am including in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `link` of `\includepdf` adds a link `<file name>.<page number>` for each included page. This can be used to specify the destination for a bookmark link:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\bookmarksetup{
  numbered,
  open,
}

\newcommand*{\myimagelist}[2]{%
  \bookmark[
    dest={#2.1},% see option `linkname' of \includepdf
    keeplevel,
    rellevel=1,
  ]{#1 (\detokenize{#2})}%
  \includepdf[
    fitpaper,
    link,
    % linkname={#2},% see option `dest' of \bookmark
  ]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Images}

\myimagelist{some label}{some path/pdffile1}
\myimagelist{some other label}{some path/pdffile2}

\end{document}
```

In the example above, the bookmark contains both the label and the file name is appended in parentheses. Also it is possible to put the file name in another bookmark:

```
\newcommand*{\myimagelist}[2]{%
  \bookmark[
    dest={#2.1},% see option `linkname' of \includepdf
    keeplevel,
    rellevel=1,
  ]{#1}%
  \bookmark[
    dest={#2.1},% see option `linkname' of \includepdf
    keeplevel,
    rellevel=2,
  ]{\detokenize{#2}}%
  \includepdf[
    fitpaper,
    link,
    % linkname={#2},% see option `dest' of \bookmark
  ]{#2}%
}
```

I have put the file name in `\detokenize` to avoid trouble with `_`.

Comment: You are a genius! How about bookmarks according to figure file names?

Comment: @Laura What do you mean, the bookmark text is the same as the file name (`some path/pdffile1`) instead of `some label`? Then just use `#2` instead of `#1` for the mandatory argument of `\bookmark`.

Comment: And even more complicated, nested bookmarks for figure labels and then figure file names? :)

Comment: Above code beautifully produces PDF with bookmarks for labels of the figures included, and not their file names. Let me try your comment suggestion, while you can think about nested case, if you be so kind.

Comment: @Laura Also the nesting request is not clear to me. Perhaps you can update the question to give an example.

Comment: You suggestion about using `#2` instead of `#1` did work. As for the nested one, I mean to have both two bookmarks for the same page, first for its label and subbookmark for the file name of that figure. In other words to link label and file name to the same figure/page of PDF. This way I will have all information about the figures.